# Given N switches, how many combinations are there where no more and no fewer than m switches are turned on?

Tags: combinatorics, induction

I realize this question has probably been asked before, but at my level of combinatorics I wasn't able to recognize it.

I used switches just as an example, obviously bits or some other abstract could be used. But basically what I want to know is

*Given 2^N combinations of switches being on or off, how can you find the subset where m switches are turned on? Where 0 ≤ m ≤ N.*

For example, if you have 4 switches (N) and were required to have any combination of 3 switches turned on (m), the solution would be 4 because of the 2^4 (32) possible combinations of the switches there are only 4 which have only 3 switches turned on.

What I really want is to come up with some formula that takes N and m and gives the length of the subset mentioned above. I feel like induction could be used for find the formula and prove it, but I haven't had any luck yet.

Thanks in advance for the help!

PS This is not a HW problem or something, I'm just honestly curious about the solution and have been thinking it over all morning.

Comment: Of the $N$ switches, choose $m$ of them to be on.  This is often written as $\binom Nm$... Specifically, this is the binomial coefficient.

Comment: Thank you for that, abiessu! I knew there were better ways to express this, but wasn't sure. So would I say: Given 2^N combinations of switches being on or off, find $\binom Nm$ where 0 <= m <= N?

Comment: "*Find $\binom{N}{m}$*"?  It is well known that $\binom{N}{m}=\dfrac{N!}{m!(N-m)!}$ and this can be proven in many different ways.  When abiessu said "the answer is the binomial coefficient $\binom{N}{m}$" that is how people generally express the *answer*, not the *question*.

Comment: To reiterate, the [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) $\binom{N}{m}$ is the answer to the question of "in how many ways can you choose exactly $m$ objects out of $N$ available distinct objects where order of selection is irrelevant.  Alternately phrased, it is the number of subsets of size $m$ from a set of size $N$.  It is often read aloud as "$N$ choose $m$."  Binomial coefficients are among the first tools and results learned when learning introductory combinatorics and counting techniques, right behind rule of product and rule of sum.

Comment: Awesome! abiessu, JMoravitz, thank you so much! And thanks for your patience with my lack of knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a binary string of length `n`

First, your task is to choose a position to set a bit to `1`.
How many ways can you choose a bit from the available `n` unset bits? (`n` ways)

After that, your task is to choose a position to set another bit to `1`.
How many ways can you choose a bit from the remaining `n-1` unset bits? (`n-1` ways)

See any pattern?

---

If the length of the string is `10`,
and if you want to set exactly 4 of the bits to `1`,
it seems you can do it in `10*9*8*7` ways.  But...